# how to compare two arrays for inequality in python? (greater for example)

Tags: python, arrays, comparison, inequality

does anybody know how to do comparison between two arrays in python? I almost tried everything but didn't work out. Could some body help?
what i mean is that for all the elements one array/list is greater in same shape for both arrays;

(`a = numpy.array([[1, 2, 3]]
b = numpy.array([[4, 5, 6]]))`

then b is greater than a

Comment: So what does it mean for one array to be "greater" than another array? Your question is very vague. Can you show us an example, two input arrays and the result of the comparison?

Comment: In order to post a question folks can help you with, you should include some data to work with, and some of the "almost everything" that you've tried that failed to work

Comment: for example a = [1, 2, 3], b= [4, 5, 6], then b is greater than a (what i meant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a straightaway comparision wont work(and probably wouldn't make sense either).

For Example following outputs *True*:

```
arr1 = [1, 4, 5]
arr2 = [2, 3, 4]
print(arr1 > arr2)
```

You could however try something like this:

```
arr1 = [1, 2, 3]
arr2 = [2, 3, 4]

count = 0
for i in range(len(arr1)):
    if(arr1[i] < arr2[i]):
        count += 1

if(count == len(arr1)):
    print("Greater for sure")
else:
    print("unsure")
```

Comment: yepp, but i'm looking whether there is a ready function or library for that

Comment: If you could convert your data into a Pandas Dataframe, then you could use this:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html

If you want to take the numpy path, then use this:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.logic.html

Comment: Yepp it worked, thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you mean but if you're simply looking to check whether two arrays (in python they're called lists) are identical it can be done like this:

```
lst_1 = [1,2,3]
lst_2 = [1,2,3]

if lst_1 == lst_2:
    print("They were the same!")
else:
    print("They weren't the same!")
```